# Grid layout float hack not working when trying to make it 3 col

Tags: html, css, grid

I was trying to practice the grid system using floats.

I have this HTML structure for this project

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
    <div class="col">5</div>
    <div class="col">6</div>
    <div class="col">7</div>
    <div class="col">8</div>
    <div class="col">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS

```
body {
  background: #246A73;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 480px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: '';
  dispay: table;
  clear: both;
}

.col {
  margin: 3% auto 0;
  height: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 850px) {
  .grid-container {
    max-width: 750px;
  }

  .col {
    float: left;
    width: 49%;
    margin: 3% 2% 0% 0%;
  }

  .col:nth-child(2n+2) {
    margin-right: 0;
    float: left;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  .grid-container {
    max-width: 900px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .grid-container {
    max-width: 1100px;
  }

  .col {
    width: 32%;
    margin: 1% 2% 0% 0;
  }

  div.col:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin-right: 0;
    float:left;
  }
}
```

I started with the mobile layout, then scale my way up for larger displays. 
All good, till I hit the 3rd media query where I am supposed to have 3 columns. 
I use on that media query the same code I used on the first one where I have 2 columns. But somehow it broke on that one and I want to know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS for `@media (min-width: 850px)` to being applied to `@media (min-width: 1200px)` as well. Which causes the second column to not have a `margin-right` at the screen size `1200px`.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 850px) {
.col:nth-child(2n+2) {
    margin-right: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

}

So you'll have to add your second column `margin-right` back in when in `@media (min-width: 1200px)`.

```
  .col:nth-child(2n+2) {
    margin-right: 2%;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4wk24mf8/2/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your flexibility in the large media queries (>1200) to this

```
.col {
   width: 32%;
   margin: 1% 0% 0% 1%;
}
```

See it [**here**](https://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/JOGKgb)